# php short url weird appearance

Tags: php, .htaccess, short-url

there are few question to ask,hope that can be clipping solved .
I want to make a short url for my web ,and setting .htaccess file to achieve it.

Here is the original url:

http://www.example.com/view/example.view.php

Here is the url I want to make short:

http://www.example.com/Herald/

Here is the .htaccess code :

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php70 .php

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^Herald$  view/example.view.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^Herald/$ view/example.view.php [NC,L]
```

And it work! But weird things appeared, such as css, jquery ,image ,all of 
web control will be failed to workI can't figure out the problem of the setting 
Please help me find the issue, Thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you considered how your .htaccess file will be structured assuming you need to 'shorten' 15 different urls?

Comment: Not really ,I  am very interesting your suggestions ,could u give me some advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path of your CSS, JS & IMAGES changes because of rewrite rule. Please add `/` at start of every CSS, JS & IMAGES.

**What is cause?**

Look at end of your URL http://www.example.com/Herald/. It look there is folder at your root directory with name `Herald`. So it search for CSS, JS & IMAGES inside folder `Herald`.

**Solution**
If you add `/` at start of your CSS, JS & IMAGES path. It search for CSS, JS & IMAGES inside `root directory.`

**For example**:

Change From

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="include/bootstrap-3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="include/bootstrap-3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="include/css/faci.css">
    <script src="include/script/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="include/bootstrap-3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <img id="real_image" src="include/img/img_default.jpg">
    <img src="include/img/ajax-loader.gif">
```

Into

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/include/bootstrap-3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/include/bootstrap-3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/include/css/faci.css">
    <script src="/include/script/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/include/bootstrap-3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <img id="real_image" src="/include/img/img_default.jpg">
    <img src="/include/img/ajax-loader.gif">
```